# FactoryBot - How can I pass a transient array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I currently have a FactoryBot trait set up as follows:

```rb
trait :with_role do
  transient do
    role { nil }
  end

  after(:create) do |staff_member, factory|
    staff_member.staff_roles << StaffRole.fetch(factory.role) if factory.role
  end
end
```

However, this  trait only allows the factory to be passed a single role. I'm refactoring a series of tests wherein mutliple roles need to be assigned. This is a M-N relationship supported both by the DB and ORM via a junction table, and clearly functions as expected outside of FactoryBot because the original test implementation passes. My approach is as follows:

```rb
# Inside the factory
trait :with_roles do
  transient do
    roles { [] }
  end

  after(:create) do |staff_member, factory|
    roles.each { |role| staff_member.staff_roles << StaffRole.fetch(factory.send(role)) }
  end
end
```

```rb
# Invocation
staff_member = FactoryBot.create(:staff_member, :with_roles, roles: [
  :role_1,
  :role_2,
  :role_3
], some_other_attribute: 1)
```

The problem is that when I try to invoke in this way, I get the following error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `roles' for #<FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner:...>
```

I get the exact same error if I initialise `roles` as `nil` instead of an empty array. The previous implementation works fine, and I've followed it as closely as possible. Why is `roles` undefined despite being defined as a transient variable? Am I missing something about how FactoryBot works, and trying to do something impossible? Or  am I just appproaching this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call [a transient attribute](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#with-callbacks) on a factory:

```rb
after(:create) do |staff_member, factory|
  factory.roles.each { |role| staff_member.staff_roles << StaffRole.fetch(factory.send(role)) }
end
```

Comment: a-HA! Looks like I misunderstood what the `factory.role` was doing in the original implementation. Thank you so much, this worked a treat.